# jQuery move elements inside a div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jQuery plugin to get some rss feeds. The plugin is FeedEk.

the usage is simple:

```
<script>
   $('#rss_div').FeedEk({
         FeedUrl: 'http://some_rss_url.feed',
         MaxCount: 5,
         ShowDesc: true,
         ShowPubDate: true,
         DescCharacterLimit: 200,
         TitleLinkTarget: '_blank
     });
```

i need to put every single feed in a separate div.

the html produced by the script is:

```
<div id="rss_div">
  <ul class="feedEkList">
    <li>
     <div class="itemTitle">....title blabla....</div>
     <div class="itemDate">.....date...</div>
     <div class="itemContent">....content...img src...blabla..</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      and so on..
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and this is what I'm trying to move elements from rss_div to other divs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divRss > li:eq(0)').appendTo('#newsContainer1');
});
```

without any success because the 'newsContainer1' div still 'empty'.

Thank you all in advance.

Edit implementing some answers:

```
<div id="rss_div"></div>
<div id="newsContainer1"></div>
<div id="newsContainer2"></div>
<script>
   $('#rss_div').FeedEk({
        FeedUrl:'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss',
        MaxCount : 2,
        ShowDesc : true,
        ShowPubDate:true,
        DescCharacterLimit:300,
        TitleLinkTarget:'_blank'
});
</script>
```

Maybe I'm doing it wrong because the rss_div is "populated" at "runtime" ?

Comment: your jQuery selector starts with `$('#divRss` , but you don't have any element with id `divRss` ... that's most probably your problem. Please note also that you're turning something looking semantically correct to something semantically wrong. List items are better displayed using `<li>` than any other tag...

Comment: `$('#newsContainer1').append( $('#rss_div li:first') )`

Comment: Yes it was only a copy/paste mistake

Answer (score 1):

You do not need imeediate child selector `>` here. also change the id selector to `#rss_div  li:eq(0)`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rss_div li:eq(0)').appendTo('#newsContainer1');
});
```

also, `li` should be wrappen in `ul` element before appending to div.

Comment: Just applied but without any success. It seems after 'rss_div' whatever tag is not recognized.

Comment: @user1291822: can you share the fiddle with relevant code.

Comment: basically this is the plugin I'm using: http://jquery-plugins.net/FeedEk/FeedEk.html

Comment: @user1291822: there is no reason for this not to work. that is the reason i am asking you for fiddle.

Comment: i'm not yet understand very well how jsfiddle works but I'm on it.

Comment: @user1291822: not a problem. take your time and let me know when fiddle is ready

Comment: ok, this is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/some_max/RU5r8/4/ and it works.. On my local project not....

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a wrong selector:

```
$('#divRss > li:eq(0)')
```

its `rss_div`:

```
$('#rss_div li:eq(0)')
```

Comment: copy/paste mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rss_div ul > li').appendTo('#newsContainer');
   // get ul inside div and its immediate li
});
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rss_div > ul > li').appendTo('#newsContainer');
    // get immediate ul inside div and its immediate li
});
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rss_div > ul li:eq(0)').appendTo('#newsContainer');
       // get immediate ul and its first li
});
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#rss_div  ul li:eq(0)').appendTo('#newsContainer');
           // get  ul inside div and its first li
    });
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WqLZC/)

Comment: i attached fiddle demo, its working you must be doing some other mistake